# HttpClient through AggregateException instead of returning HTTP code

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am using GetAsync method to read a web api get method through the following code

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:10000/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/account/balance/" + accountNumber.ToString()).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string responseJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = jss.Deserialize<AccountResponse>(responseJson);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error! Http error " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I am expecting when there is a problem with the service like authentication, page not found, or else, the relevant HTTP code should be returned and found in the HttpResponseMessage instance, but what happens is that when one of these HTTP error exist, the HttpResponseMessage throws an AggregateException when trying to GetAsync

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually getting one of those errors and there's not a bigger issue that would result in an exception? Try pointing your client at https://httpbin.org/status/404 , this should get you a response message with a 404 code and no exception.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the aggregate exception is showing because your Task operation is throwing one or more exceptions. 
Per design Task methods always throws all its exceptions in an aggregated exception and to get the real exceptions
await your tasks by using the async - await pattern

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:10000/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/account/balance/" + accountNumber.ToString());
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = jss.Deserialize<AccountResponse>(responseJson);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error! Http error " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```